# Sliding a <div> from the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to create a keypad which can slide up from the bottom using the jQuery animate. The keypad will be first hidden at the bottom of the page, and it will slide up only when I press the button. Below is the code:

```js
       $("#keypad-toggle").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         if ($("#qnumbers").hasClass("toggled")) {
           $("#qnumbers").animate({
             "height": "390px"
           }).removeClass("toggled");
           $("#num").css("display", "none");
         } else {
           $("#qnumbers").animate({
             "height": "250px"
           }).addClass("toggled");
           $("#num").css("display", "inline");
         }
       });
```

```css
#qnumbers {
  background-color: #3C4050;
  height: 390px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#keypad {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: springgreen;
  text-align: center;
}
#numpad {
  background-color: springgreen;
}
#screen {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qnumbers" class="container-fluid">
  <div id="servenumber"></div>
</div>
<div id="keypad" class="container-fluid"><a href="#keypad-toggle" id="keypad-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> Number Pad</a>

</div>
<div id="numpad" class="container-fluid">
  <div id="num" style="display:none;">
    <div id="screen">1234567890</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/obnr1akj/)

However, I have found out that there is something not right with the keypad when it slides down. My keypad will disappear first and it's background will become white before the sliding down animation occurs. What do I have to change so that the keypad will not disappear when sliding down?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#num").css("display", "none");
```

This code runs while animating. To run codes after animation done, you can attach callback function like this.

```
$("#qnumbers").animate({"height": "390px"},function(){
    $("#num").css("display", "none"); 
}).removeClass("toggled");
```

Comment: Good solution Thanks!

Comment: Do you know why is it there is a vertical scroll bar appeared every time I slide up and slide down?

Comment: Is there a way to remove the scroll bar?

Comment: @Coolguy use overflow-y:hidden CSS for removing scroll bar. In this case, `body{ overflow-y:hidden }`

Comment: @Coolguy You may want to hide only numpad part, not the other two part. then, wrap the whole contents with <div "height:420px; (which means 390+30) overflow-y:hidden;">

Answer (score 0):

Please see my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/gv3opxcf/).

I edited your open toggle code so that it will show after the toggle using a callback on the animation:

```
    if ($("#qnumbers").hasClass("toggled")) {
        $("#qnumbers").animate({
            "height": "390px"
        }, function() { /* added callback for animation */
           $("#num").hide();
        }).removeClass("toggled");
    }
```

Comment: Do you know why is it there is a vertical scroll bar appeared every time I slide up and slide down? It look kinda wierd.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the scroll bar?

Comment: I'm not sure, it depends on the height of your containers. maybe you could give the body element overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 0):

you could adjust the height of the numpad element instead of hiding its contents, this way your keypad will slide in and out smoothly. also you would like to set the box sizing of your "screen" to border-box if you plan on having the border fully visible without too many height adjustments:

```js
       $("#keypad-toggle").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         if ($("#qnumbers").hasClass("toggled")) {
           $("#qnumbers").animate({
             "height": "390px"
           }).removeClass("toggled");
           $("#numpad").animate({
             "height": "0"
           });
         } else {
           $("#qnumbers").animate({
             "height": "250px"
           }).addClass("toggled");
           $("#numpad").animate({
             "height": "140px"
           });
         }
       });
```

```css
#qnumbers {
  background-color: #3C4050;
  height: 390px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#keypad {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: springgreen;
  text-align: center;
}
#numpad {
  background-color: springgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
#screen {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 140px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qnumbers" class="container-fluid">
  <div id="servenumber"></div>
</div>
<div id="keypad" class="container-fluid"><a href="#keypad-toggle" id="keypad-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> Number Pad</a>

</div>
<div id="numpad" class="container-fluid">
  <div id="num">
    <div id="screen">1234567890</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is a fixed <kbd>**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/obnr1akj/6/)**</kbd>